# Reestablish wired connection after router reboots

Tags: debian, raspbian, dhcp

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Revision 1.1(<sub>an old but capable computer on a chip</sub>)

Software: Linux pi 5.10.17-v7+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:29:51 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux (<sub>a headless Raspbian, updated daily</sub>)

Problem: if the router to which the pi is **wired** is rebooted, it never again obtains an IP address unless rebooted itself. The router has DHCP enabled, serves various other clients well and even has address reservation for pi's MAC (which it honors on initial connection).

I don't have a screen attached to observe the process. What logs should I read? What is the canonical solution? I have tried `raspi-config`, `/etc/network/interfaces` and `crontab` to no avail.

---

EDIT:

I am coming to realise because of all the help by **@roaima** that probably this is the problem:

```
root@pi:~# tail /var/log/messages
Apr  8 17:03:00 pi kernel: [19266.854548] rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 7 callbacks suppressed
Apr  8 17:03:00 pi kernel: [19266.854563] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Apr  8 17:03:34 pi kernel: [19300.134515] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Apr  8 17:04:13 pi kernel: [19339.654471] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Apr  8 17:04:35 pi kernel: [19361.544887] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enxb827ebaa0989 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:07:b6:8a:5a:89:08:00:46:00:00:20:00:00:40:00:01:02:44:2d SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  8 17:06:40 pi kernel: [19486.644998] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enxb827ebaa0989 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:07:b6:8a:5a:89:08:00:46:00:00:20:00:00:40:00:01:02:44:2d SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  8 17:07:14 pi kernel: [19520.614323] rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 6 callbacks suppressed
Apr  8 17:08:39 pi kernel: [19605.894239] rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 6 callbacks suppressed
Apr  8 17:08:39 pi kernel: [19605.894255] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Apr  8 17:08:45 pi kernel: [19611.745141] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enxb827ebaa0989 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:07:b6:8a:5a:89:08:00:46:00:00:20:00:00:40:00:01:02:44:2d SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=
```

There are a lot more of those `ufw` errors while the undervoltage messages have never been an issue (I use an underspecced PS).

Comment: Do you mean that the Pi loses its address, or that it doesn't ask the router for a refresh?

Comment: @roaima the Pi doesn't get any IP at all: I `nmap` the router to be sure. Also I wait for 10 minutes.

Comment: So it loses its current address?

Comment: @roaima hmmm how can I know that? If I ping it, `the host is down`. If I scan some ports it opens at boot - they are not open. The router's DHCP address reservation time is 120minutes, which sounds irrelevant as there's a MAC->IP binding for the pi.

Comment: The scenario I'm trying to understand is this. Router on. Pi on. Pi gets IP address from router. All is good. Use `ip a` to view the IP address for the wired connection. Router is restarted. At this point, on the Pi does `ip a` still show the correct expected IP address for the Pi? If not, has it gone entirely or has it changed? (If it has changed does it start 169.254?)